# IE/FF cannot find video to play HTML5 when on the webserver.- Chrome plays fine

Tags: html, internet-explorer, video, html5-video

I'm pretty sure this is a path issue but it's killing me, i cannot figure out the correct path to find the video.  When I run this on my local machine it works just fine.  When I run this server side in Chrome it works just fine.  FF and IE however come back with "Cannot find this video".

Thanks!

`<td width="225"><video controls poster="Approving.jpg" width="200" height="200" preload controls>
  <source src="Approving.mp4" type="video/mp4">
  <object type="application/x-shockwave-flash" data="NonverBlaster.swf"
width="225" height="129">
    <param name="allowfullscreen" value="true">
    <param name="allowscriptaccess" value="always">
    <param name="flashvars" value="file=Approving.mp4">
    <!--[if IE]><param name="movie" value="NonverBlaster.swf"><![endif]-->
    <img src="Approving.jpg" width="854" height="480" alt="Video">
    <p>Your browser can’t play HTML5 video. <a href="video.webm">
Download it</a> instead.</p>
  </object>
</video></td>`

Comment: @Rob3 If you are going to edit, please fix the messed up code...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the quintessential example of what happens when you walk away for a day and come back.

What was happening is I was browsing the HTML file through windows explorer instead of using IE/FF to go to IP/Port/index.HTML of the actual HTML.

Interestingly chrome know to look on the local server for the file.